# Correlation of gene expression data on survival data in R cor.test, corr.test, or corr?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation, genetics

So I have a very large dataframe that is laid out like so in this example:

```
line    gene1    gene2    gene3    gene4    gene5  survival
1       4.05     7.65     0.25     0.789    10.5   0.90
2       2.51     4.36     12.5     7.56     8.99   0.50
3       3.65     2.55     48.8     5.65     5.89   0.25   
4       5.65     1.54     8.99     9.2      0.01   0.10
```

The only difference is that I am dealing with over 18,000 genes in my actual data. `line` refers to genetic lines of flies while the numbers in each "gene" column refer to relative gene expression. `survival` is the proportion of survival in each line. What I would like to do is correlate columns 2 through 5 (gene expressions) with column 6 (`survival`). I have tried this with `cor` and it works fine:

```
cor1<-cor(master2[c(2:5)], master2$surv, method="pearson")
```

However, I want to do this with either `cor.test` or `corr.test` (from `psych` package) to output p-values and do some corrections on them.

I've tried:

```
cor1<-cor.test(master2[c(2:5)], master2$surv, method="pearson")
```

and get:

```
Error in cor.test.default(master2[c(2:5)], master2$surv, method = "pearson") : 
'x' and 'y' must have the same length
```

And I've also tried:

```
cor1<-corr.test(master2[c(2:18141)], master2$surv, method="pearson")
```

And get:

```
Error in 1:ncol(y) : argument of length 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance,

Phil

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in my experience doing something similar with a large gene expression dataset, `psych::corr.test()` is **far** superior, especially for matrix by matrix or df by df.

The advantage of `psych::corr.test()` is also the reason why you are getting that error. The two inputs must both be either matrices or dataframes - when you use `master2$surv` to extract one column it is no longer a dataframe! Try using `master2[,ncol(master2)]` to extract the last column.

Edit:

You will be able to use `cor.test` as well but you will need to `sapply` across the columns of interest in the first argument i.e. `2:5` in your example. Performance wise if it is 4 columns it is likely no big deal but if it is thousands I would recommend `pysch::corr.test`.

Comment: I tried: 
    cor1<-corr.test(master2[c(2:18141)],master2$surv[,ncol(master2],method="pearson") and get an error (Error: unexpected ']' in "cor1<-corr.test(master2[c(2:18141)], master2$surv[,ncol(master2]") 
So then i tried: cor1<-corr.test(master2[c(2:18141)], master2$surv[,ncol(master2)], method="pearson") and got Error in master2$surv[, ncol(master2)] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: Apologies, that was a copy paste error on my end. You want `master2[,ncol(master2)]` rather than `master2$surv[,ncol(master2)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to implement the `apply` mentioned above. First subset your variables as matrices:

```
mat <- df[, 2:5]
survival <- df[, 6]
```

Now apply `cor.test()` across the columns of `mat`:

```
cor <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) cor.test(survival, x))
```

Extract correlation coefficients with

```
unlist(sapply(cor, "[", 4))
```

18,000 variables should be easily doable on a decent machine.